# i have converted excel data into json using npm library convert-excel-to-json but now I have to use async.eachSeries to insert data into mongoDb ,how?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web, async.js

/*  I have to use async.eachSeries to insert and validate duplicate
data but the library is returning array of objects ,How can I do
it Can anyone help
*/

```
     app.post("/",upload.single("excel"),(req,res)=>{
        const result = excelToJson({
            sourceFile: req.file.path
        });
       asyncs.eachSeries(result,(input,callback)=>{
    })

   
})
    //  //Example of data
    //  {
    //    Sheet1: [
    //      {
    //        A: 'Name of the Candidate',
    //        B: 'Email',
    //        C: 'Mobile No.',
    //        D: 'Date of Birth',
    //        E: 'Work Experience',
    //        F: 'Resume Title',
    //        G: 'Current Location',
    //        H: 'Postal Address',
    //        I: 'Current Employer',
    //        J: 'Current Designation'
    //      },
    //      {
    //        A: 'Ashish Kumar',
    //        B: 'assignment1@klimbdemo.com',
    //        C: 9876543211,
    //        D: 1991-11-15T18:29:50.000Z,
    //        E: '5 Year(s)',
    //        F: 'Front End JavaScript Developer, with 2 years of experience in customer interaction interface design and development',
    //        G: 'Bengaluru',
    //        H: 'H.No. 22, Street 12, Indra Nagar, Bengalure, Karnataka',
    //        I: 'Logly',
    //        J: 'Member of Technical Staff'
    //      }]
    //  //I have to use this data in async.eachSeries//
```